# How to inject a service into a ES6 helper class

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Consider the following component

```
import DoSomethingSpecial from '....';

export default MyComponentController {
    constructor() {
         this.result = new DoSomethingSpecial().getData();
    }
    ...
}
```

So, the `MyComponentController` is of course a controller for a component and the `DoSomethingSpecial` class is an ES215 class.

The problem I have is as follows: Inside `DoSomethingSpecial` I would like to use some angular services, like $http and/or $q, etc. How can I inject these into this class, for example:

```
export default class DoSomethingSpecial {
     constructor() {

     }

     getData() {
          let $q = angular.injector().get('$q');
          ....
     }
}
```

This however doesn't work. Is there an other way, or should I change this class to a service ?

**UPDATE**: A possible use case: Suppose you download in a service a list of objects, which you convert into instances of MyRecordItems as follows

```
import MyRecordItem from '...';

export default class MyRecordsService {
     constructor($http) {
         $http.get('url', { options}).then((response) => {
             this.records = [];

             response.data.forEach((item) => {
                 this.records.push(new MyRecordItem(item));
             });
         });
    }
}
```

Next, somewhere in you app this list is used -> modified -> and saved

```
let list = myRecordService.getList();
list[0].count = 10;
list[0].save();
```

How does this record persist itself ? It could be as follows

```
 export default class MyRecordItem {
     constructor(data) { this.data = data; }
     save() {
         let url = ....;
         return angular.$injector.get('$http').post(url, this.data)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Now that's weird. `DoSomethingSpecial` is not an Angular service, but uses Angular services?

Comment: Good point, I've spend some time to think of a use case, which I've added to my post

Comment: `save()` is called from within an Angular service or controller. So why not call `save($http)` or `save($http.post)`?

Comment: Well, suppose you have that **list** inside a `component`, which in your case would mean the directive needs some knowledge of how data is persisted and it needs the $http to be injected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the dependencies that your ES6 class needs to the controller's constructor (`$q` in this case). After you've injected `$q` to the controller, create an instance of the class, and pass `$q` as a parameter to the constructor. Assign the instance to `this`.

```
import DoSomethingSpecial from '....';

class MyComponentController {

     constructor($q) {
        'ngInject';

       this.doSomethingSpecialInstance = new DoSomethingSpecial($q); // instantiate the service, and pass the dependencies
     }

     getData() {
          this.result = doSomethingSpecialInstance().getData(); // use the instance
     }
}

export default MyComponentController;
```

And the class definition:

```
export default class DoSomethingSpecial {
  constructor($q) {
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  getData() {
    // do something with this.$q
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this will only work if the class is used as a service. For example if I do: `let x = new DoSomethingSpecial();` how does angular know it should inject something, because it is not involved here.

Comment: It took me awhile to get your meaning. See my updated answer.

Comment: It sounds like the only valid solution :) Thnx

Comment: One other interesting solution might be to add `$q` or `$http` somewhere in the config phase to a static property of `MyRecordItem` like: `MyRecordItem.$q = $q;`

Comment: You can config the class module in the run phase, and pass $injector to it. Now you can use $injector to get whatever the class need on config, or when instantiating. Nice idea.